# Wordpress - How to import html code into a page?

Tags: wordpress

What I would like to do is have a html form that I will place at the end of most of my pages. I am not planning to have it on every page, but most.

Edit: I realized after posting that I didn't make it clear enough that I don't mean in the footer, but something I would like to add on the page itself.

Of course I could simply copy in the full html and css code at the bottom of the pages I want it on. However I know there is a better and cleaner way to have my html form and css in one file and then either through making a plugin, use of short code, html code or some other option I'm not aware of, import the html code into the page.

So what would be a good approach to accomplish this?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This might help, *custom post types*: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: Put the code into your footer and display it conditionally.

Comment: Sorry, I realized after posting that I didn't make it clear enough that I don't mean in the footer, but something I would like to add on the page itself. And thanks Dan, I will look into custom post types and once I understand it, I will see how I can use it for my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to [create a custom page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) that includes the form and just select that template when you need it.

This approach would not work well if you're already utilizing more than one page template. See [@Hakem's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30563387/3250005) if that is the case.

Answer (score 2):

Custom Fields could help? this is the fastest way i could think of. Alternatively you could use shortcodes
edit page.php file and add the following in the loop:

```
<?php if(get_post_meta(get_the_id(),"add_custom_form", TRUE)){ ?>
    <p>some custom html here</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Then go to the pages you want to add the form to, and add a custom field "add_custom_form" with any value.

Comment: actually @mtinsley answer's better.

Comment: Actually I think it depends. If you already have several page templates my approach would not work. You would have to setup a custom field like you suggested and incorporate the form into each template.

Comment: That's true, but in this specific question your solution is much more suitable.